# Managed Propoerties - Crawled Properties were NOT generated for renamed Title Columns of SPlists and document libraries

Tags: enterprise-search, managed-property, crawled-property, title-column, search-schema

Am facing issue in search while searching for renamed `Title` columns from various `SPLists` and `DocumentLibraries` in my publishing site collection. Say projectrequestnumber is the renamed column of the Title of my splist "ProjectRequest" and another splist called "projectproposal" also created with projproposalno as the renamed title column.

So if I want to create managed properties of these title columns in the `search schema` of my search service application, it failed to provide the managed properties /crawled properties .

Am stuck on this issue and thinking about how to resolve this. I have not created site columns or custom content types for these splists and document libraries. I went ahead with simple doc.lib columns and splist columns for my application.

My Env is:SP 2013 Stnd.Edition with Ent.Search Center and Search Service Application. 
   [image: managed-prop]

Comment: Did you run full crawl after that?

Comment: Yes, i have run full crawl multiple times  but am getting the usual ows_title only in the managed properties. As per my requirement, i want to get these projectrequestno and projectpropoalno as refiners in my search results page. but somehow its not happening.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're not actually creating a new field, you're simply updating the **DisplayName** property of the **Title** field. Since crawled/managed properties already exist for the **Title** field, no new properties are necessary and thus are not created.

[SPField Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa979575.aspx)

[Crawled/Managed Property Reference](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/03/05/from-site-column-to-managed-property-whats-up-with-that/)

Comment: so, what should be done in order to generate managed properties , crawled properties for my splistTitle field and document libraries?

Comment: If you are working with enterprise CAL version of SharePoint, you can look for Content enrichment processing which allows you to modify the managed properties of crawled items before they are indexed.  [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163982.aspx)

Comment: They already exist, no need to generate them. The values for your renamed fields should already be indexed in the Title fields managed property. If you really want to, you can create new managed properties with whatever names you like, and map the crawled properties for the Title field to them.